# Is it useful to have navigation/location labels and the page title duplicating information?

Tags: navigation, layout, page-layout

Navigation already tells you where you are. Do we need a title? Is it useful or is the title information just increasing interaction cost?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two regions on that page - a navigation region and the page content. Therefor I would say it would make sense to re-enforce the association between the navigation item and its page content.

When you are working on the page content you are not interested in navigation, so you need to ensure the person using this can easily be reminded about what page they are on by showing a clear title. There is no interaction cost because the title is not something you interact with.

Comment: Also semantically and SEO purposes ( if any ) there should be a header in the page.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. That's what my intuition told me, but I started second guessing myself. :-)